# Question from Katok and Hasselblat (Exercise 4.3.1)

Tags: dynamical-systems, entropy, ergodic-theory

I was trying to solve question 4.3.1 from Katok and Hasselblat but I couldn't make my argument complete. Could you look at it?

This is the question.

Let $\xi, \eta \in \mathcal{P}_m$. Prove that for any $\epsilon > 0$ there is $\delta > 0$ such that $d_R(\xi, \eta) < \delta$ implies $D(\xi, \delta) < \epsilon$. Here

- $d_R$ is the Rokhlin metric;
- $$D(\xi, \eta) := \min_{\sigma \in \mathbb{S}_m} \sum_{i = 1}^n \mu(\xi \Delta \eta_{\sigma(i)});$$
- $\mathcal{S}_m$ is the set of all permutations on $m$ elements;
  and
- $\mathcal{P}_m$ is the set of all measurable partitions with exactly $m$ elements for the probability space $(X, \mu).

This is my thoughts/ideas (I overexplain things. Sorry in advance.)

[image]
[image]
[image]